Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<MyModel>'
I'm getting this error when trying to convert dynamic List to MyModel List.

Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<SMSModel>'

What I have tried is below, yet still returning the above error.
List<SMSModel> list = data.cast<SMSModel>();


Could show the content of data or even better include a minimal reproducible example?

Depending on where your data is coming from you might need to handle this differently.
If data is of type Map
If the data you are trying to convert into SMSModel comes from an external API call (Firestore or similar), you might need to first convert the dynamic into Map<String, dynamic>, before calling something like SMSModel.fromJson(...) on it.
Steps

Turn List<dynamic> into List<Map<String, dynamic>>

final listOfMap = data.map((itemData) => Map<String, dynamic>.from(itemData as Map));


Turn List<Map<String, dynamic>> into List<SMSModel>

final smsModels = listOfMap.map((item) => SMSModel.fromJson(item));

If Type of data has been lost in client (somehow?)
If you at some point have had data as List<SMSModel> but this is now lost in some translation, try to simply do a final smsModels = List<SMSModel>.from(data); and see what you get back.

tried this solution but another error shows.
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: type 'MappedListIterable<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List'

So, most likely data is not of type List<dynamic> (as your title suggests), but dynamic?

ahh yes, it's dynamic data only

Then you might be able to do the following conversion:
final dataMap = Map<String, dynamic>.from(itemData as Map);
Depending on how much you know about the data that you're handling here, you might need to "debug" your way to understanding its structure. I'd print the result and see what I'm converting here.
print(dataMap);
It might be something in the shape of a JSON response {status: "success", data: [ ... ] /your list here/)}, or it might be the data of one SMSModel. You need to figure this out in order to continue your parsing correctly.
